# jquery Selector with conditions "attribute" less then

Tags: jquery, performance

Good morning,

just for my thirst of knowledge I'm interested in the question if there is a possibility to optimize the following simple function.

```
$('.item').each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    if (el.data('timestamp') < 1374033452)
        el.addClass('processed');
});
```

It may happen, that the selector for ".item" returns over a hundred, in a worst-case even thousands of elements and this is not really performing very well.
Timestamp is a unix-timestamp value added to the data-attribute of every .item.

Kind regards,

Dominik

Comment: If timestamp is added in the HTML, then using getAttribute is probably faster. But I don't know if that might make a real difference.

Comment: If you have to issue this several times, it might be possible to arrange things that the subsequent evaluations are faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery adds a lot of overhead. You can go more than ten times faster by just using vanilla JS :

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
for (var i=elements.length; i-->0;) {
  if (elements[i].getAttribute('data-timestamp') < 1374033452) {
     elements[i].className = 'processed';
  }
}
```

(note that I supposed you could replace all classes, not just add)

[JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-filter/2)

But the performance problem you experience might be more related to the cost of the [reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow) than to the simple JavaScript execution. For example if the `processed` class changes the dimensions of the element, it may force a big reflow. It's possible there is more gain to find here than on the pure jQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I just tested on Firefox (see [perfs](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-filter/2)). Results are impressive and maybe weird...

Comment: +1 if I could give you one, my reputation here is still to low - damned ... heavy ... and good to see. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: @DominikHabichtsberg No worry. The accept and the kind comment are enough ;)

Comment: @dystroy :-) I added another variant to [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-filter/3) ... I have the problem, that I need to add the class and also to keep the other classes ...
An item may have various states and they should be kept.
The only thing I do not know is, how to increase the performance for this

Comment: Well, the performance looks fine. Don't forget that 1000 times the loop per second is already faster than what you need and that the real cost isn't depicted here but is the one of the reflow, which depends on your page and the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
$('.item').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('timestamp') < 1374033452
}).addClass('processed');
```

Sample: [Profiling](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-filter)

Comment: Would it be faster ? I don't see why.

Comment: @dystroy marginally according to this profiling http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-filter

Comment: That's interesting. There's a real gain. It might be related to the big overhead at the start of the addClass function. +1 from me.

Comment: In fact going full native is still ten times faster (see my answer).

Comment: @Arun thanks for your suggestion... I'll keep that in mind for future things ... if I don't solve 'em natively.
Till now, I wasn't aware of the filter functionality

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.item').addClass(function(){
    return this.getAttribute('data-timestamp') < 1374033452 ? 'processed' : '';
});
```

Comment: +1 again the condition was inverses in your case, now a marginal +3% http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-filter

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Oh, didn't notice I reversed the condition, thanks. As for speed, it's so marginal that it doesn't matter anyway, but I'm suprised that filter is faster than this one when using the native getAttribute etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can solve it the first time around, but subsequent calls, you possibly could with this:

```
$(".item:not('.processed')").each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    if (el.data('timestamp') < 1374033452)
        el.addClass('processed');
});
```

But I don't know if this fits your usecase.

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/